# Codeigniter do_upload return 1, but no video in the folder

Tags: codeigniter

In codeigniter I tried to upload a video, in the localhost its working fine but for server do_upload returning 1, and when I show uploaded data file_path showing extray /var/www/abcd/data/ before my main domain mysite.com.

Finally   /var/www/abcd/data/mysite.com  the folder where uploading writable, every thing is fine in my localhost.

Comment: Please, add to question your code. CI logs are empty?

Comment: Can you tell me please how to check CI logs?

Comment: Logs folder located in `application/logs` or `php_logs_path/php_error_log`. Also if you want to use CI logs, it's must be enabled in `application/config/config.php` `$config['log_threshold'] = 1;`